# How to find the offending record from Elasticsearch Painless _reindex script error message?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm running a `_reindex` on a large-ish index, and getting this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "runtime error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "ctx._source.es_resync_time = ctx._source.es_resync_time / 1000000;\n        }\n      }\n      ",
          "                                        ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : " ...",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "position" : {
          "offset" : 1911,
          "start" : 1871,
          "end" : 1962
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "script_exception",
    "reason" : "runtime error",
    "script_stack" : [
      "ctx._source.es_resync_time = ctx._source.es_resync_time / 1000000;\n        }\n      }\n      ",
      "                                        ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script" : " ...",
    "lang" : "painless",
    "position" : {
      "offset" : 1911,
      "start" : 1871,
      "end" : 1962
    },
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "class_cast_exception",
      "reason" : "Cannot apply [/] operation to types [java.lang.String] and [java.lang.Integer]."
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

The error is legit and I'd be happy to improve my script, but I'd like to have a bit more context. Is there a way to see the offending value or its record id from the error message? Is there a try/catch method I can use in the script for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can try/catch the statement and then [Debug](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/8.7/painless-debugging.html) any value from the source like this

```
try {
    ctx._source.es_resync_time = ctx._source.es_resync_time / 1000000;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.explain(ctx._source)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code is a "class_cast_exception" that occurs when trying to apply the division (/) operation to a string and an integer. To fix it, you need to ensure that the "es_resync_time" field is of numeric type before performing the division operation.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "try {",
          "  if (ctx._source.es_resync_time instanceof String) {",
          "    ctx._source.es_resync_time = Double.parseDouble(ctx._source.es_resync_time);",
          "  }",
          "  ctx._source.es_resync_time = ctx._source.es_resync_time / 1000000;",
          "} catch (e) {",
          "  ctx._source.error_message = e.toString();",
          "}"
        ],
        "script": "...",
        "lang": "painless",
        "position": {
          "offset": 1911,
          "start": 1871,
          "end": 1962
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "try {",
      "  if (ctx._source.es_resync_time instanceof String) {",
      "    ctx._source.es_resync_time = Double.parseDouble(ctx._source.es_resync_time);",
      "  }",
      "  ctx._source.es_resync_time = ctx._source.es_resync_time / 1000000;",
      "} catch (e) {",
      "  ctx._source.error_message = e.toString();",
      "}"
    ],
    "script": "...",
    "lang": "painless",
    "position": {
      "offset": 1911,
      "start": 1871,
      "end": 1962
    },
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "class_cast_exception",
      "reason": "Cannot apply [/] operation to types [java.lang.String] and [java.lang.Integer]."
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: I understand the error, as said in the OP. My question is: _"Is there a way to see the offending value or its record id from the error message? Is there a try/catch method I can use in the script for this?"_

Comment: By doing (changed my answer) this, you can retrieve the specific error message that caused the exception, including information about the offending value, record ID, or any other relevant details.